# Retrofit parse JSON dynamic keys

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I'm a newbie in Retrofit. How to parse the Json below using retrofit?

```
{
   "data": {
      "Aatrox": {
         "id": 266,
         "title": "a Espada Darkin",
         "name": "Aatrox",
         "key": "Aatrox"
      },
      "Thresh": {
         "id": 412,
         "title": "o Guardião das Correntes",
         "name": "Thresh",
         "key": "Thresh"
       }
   },
   "type":"champion",
   "version":"6.23.1"
}
```

Comment: You don't parse with Retrofit - You deserialize / parse with Gson.

Comment: Anyways, `data` should be a list. So, `"data": [{ "name": "Aatrox", ...}, {"name": "Thresh", ...}]`. That will make it more suited for the format expected by a Gson POJO class

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could make your model POJO contain a `Map<String, Champion>` to deserialize into, to deal with the dynamic keys.

Example:

```
public class ChampionData {
    public Map<String, Champion> data;
    public String type;
    public String version;
}

public class Champion {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String name;
    public String key;
}
```

I'm not familiar with Retrofit besides that, but as someone in the comments said, the deserializing is done by Gson:

```
public ChampionData champions = new Gson().fromJson(json, ChampionData.class);
```

So to build on to the answer someone else posted, you can then do the following, assuming you've added the `GsonConverterFactory`:

```
public interface API {
    @GET("path/to/endpoint")
    Call<ChampionData> getChampionData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Retrofit2, the first thing you need to do is call following when building your `Retrofit` instance.

`addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Then it's just a matter of writing a POJO (e.g. MyPojoClass) that maps to the json and then adding something like following to your Retrofit interface.

`Call<MyPojoClass> makeRequest(<some params>)`;